# Getting corresponding values from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

my problem is that I can't really get my problem down in words which makes it hard to google it, so I am forced to ask you. I hope you will shed light on my issue:

I got a data.frame like this:

```
6 4
5 2
3 6
0 7
0 2
1 3
6 0
1 1
```

As you noticed, in the first column I got `0` repeating two times, `1` two times and so one. What I would like to do is get get all the corresponging values for one number, say `0`, in the second columns (in this example `7` and `2`). Preferably in `data.frame`.

I know the attempt with `df$V2[which(df$V1==0)]`, however since the first column might have over 100 rows I can't really use this. Do you guys have a good solution?

Maybe some words regarding the background of this question: I need to process this data, i.e. get the mean of the second column for all `0`'s in the first columns, or get min/max values.

Regards

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(mean = mean(V2), max=max(V2), min=min(V2))` will give you the mean, min, and max of the values in `V2` corresponding to each value of `V1`.

Comment: Why couldn't you use your function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution using `dplyr`

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(ME=mean(V2))
```

Comment: thanks for your fast and your hint about `dplyr` package! I didn't know about this very powerful package. Solved my problem like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using your data (with some temporary names attached)

```
txt <- "6 4
5 2
3 6
0 7
0 2
1 3
6 0
1 1"
df <- read.table(text = txt)
names(df) <- paste0("Var", seq_len(ncol(df)))
```

Coerce the first column to be a factor

```
df <- transform(df, Var1 = factor(Var1))
```

Then you can use `aggregate()` with a nice formula interface

```
aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, mean)
aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, max)
aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, min)
```

(eg:

```
> aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, mean)
  Var1 Var2
1    0  4.5
2    1  2.0
3    3  6.0
4    5  2.0
5    6  2.0
```

) or using the default interface

```
with(df, aggregate(Var2, list(Var1), FUN = mean))

> with(df, aggregate(Var2, list(Var1), FUN = mean))
  Group.1   x
1       0 4.5
2       1 2.0
3       3 6.0
4       5 2.0
5       6 2.0
```

But the output is nicer from the formula interface.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(mean=mean(V2), max= max(V2), min=min(V2)), by = V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what exactly is the issue with the solution you suggest?  Is it a question of efficiency?  Frankly the code you present is close to optimal [1].

For the general case, you're probably looking at a split-apply-combine action, to apply a function to subsets of the data based on some differentiator.  As @teucer points out, `dplyr` (and it's ancestor, `plyr`) are designed for exactly this, as is `data.tables`.  In vanilla R, you would tend to use `by` or `aggregate` (or `split` and `sapply` for more advanced usage) for the same task.  For example, to compute group means, you would do

```
by(df$V2, df$V1, mean)
```

or

```
aggregate(df, list(type=df$V1), mean)
```

Or even

```
sapply(split(df$V2, df$V1), mean)
```

[1] The code can be simplified to `df$V2[df$V1 == 0]` or `df[df$V1 == 0,]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies. I decided to go for the `dplyr` solution posted by teucer and eipi10. Since I have a third (and maybe even a fourth) column, this solution seems to be pretty easy to use (just adding `V3` to `group_by`).

Since some are asking what's wrong with `df$V2[which(df$V1==0)]`: I maybe was a bit unclear when saying "rows", was I actually meant was "values". Let's assume I had `n` distinct values in the first column, I would have to use the command `n` times for all distinct values and store the `n` resulting vectors.